# Flask app: The website cannot be reached 127.0.0.1 has refused the connection

Tags: python, flask

I have written a simple flask app:

```
from flask import Flask,request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle

app=Flask(__name__)
pickle_in=open('classifier_new.pkl','rb')
classifier=pickle.load(pickle_in)

def welcome():
    return "Welcome All"


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

The console tells me:

```
* Serving Flask app "bankAuth_app" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But when I try to visit the http://127.0.0.1:5000/ I get:

```
The website cannot be reached 
127.0.0.1 has refused the connection.

Try the following:

Check connection
Check proxy and firewall
```

What can I do here? I am not using a proxy and I do not know why the firewall should be responsible here...

Comment: I found the error: `@app.route('/')` was missing before `def welcome():`